# Android thermometer

Tags: android, battery, temperature

Is it possible to implement a thermometer in Android? How?

I know that the `BatteryManager` can give you the battery temperature with [BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html#EXTRA_TEMPERATURE), but I'm not sure if this can be used to somewhat accurately measure the external temperature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While StanislavK answer is technically correct, after reading the latest [Android Compatibility Definition](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/source.android.com/en//compatibility/android-2.3-cdd.pdf) I've discovered that the thermometer sensor is deprecated, and if included, it must measure CPU temperature. From the official document:

> Device implementations MAY but SHOULD
>   NOT include a thermometer (i.e.
>   temperature sensor.) If a device
>   implementation does include a
>   thermometer, it MUST measure the
>   temperature of the device CPU. It MUST
>   NOT measure any other temperature.
>   (Note that this sensor type is
>   deprecated in the Android 2.3 APIs.)

Thus, it appears that for the current version of Android it is not possible to implement an accurate thermometer.

Answer (score 2):

First, you must have a device with the thermometer sensor (a temperature sensor type). Then you might use it.

To check for the sensor, in code use [SensorManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html):

```
//get sensor manager first
SensorManager sensorMgr = (SensorManager)context.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
```

then use [getSensorList](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getSensorList%28int%29) and look for [TYPE_TEMPERATURE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html) .

**Tips:** 
Note, the temperature updates might be "slow" i.e. there might be one or two updates per minute. You might also consider to alow to calibrate your results (i.e. allow add/substract units to the built in sensor results based on a real measured temperature).

**BTW**: For an outside temeratures, you might use "current outside temperature" from the weather services like METAR (based on the current device location).

Comment: Thanks StanislavK. Do you know if most Android devices come with a thermometer sensor?